# I've tried comparator and various other strategies, and I just can't sort an ArrayList of objects using doubles.

Tags: java, arraylist, double, comparator, comparable

Hi and thanks for at least visiting.

I promise I've checked every question that's seemed relevant to what I need to do. I've tried every solution on the site and most on Google.

What I'm attempting to do is create a personality quiz that matches you to a certain trait. The desired program result is that the highest matched trait will display first. After the person tests, calculations are done to see what percentage a person is of each trait and that percentage is stored in doubles.
So I'm trying to order or sort an arraylist of objects based on this double. I've tried various strategies, but I'll give you the current two:

**With Comparable**

```
public static class results implements Comparable<results>
{
    private double rPercent; //I've tried public and just leaving it double
    public results(double percent)
    {
        this.rPercent = percent;
        Percent*=100;
        System.out.printf("You are %.2f," percent);
        System.out.println();
    }
    public double getPercent()
    {
        return rPercent;
    }
    public int CompareTo(results Percent)
    {
        double p1 = (results Percent).getX();
        double p2 = this.X - p1;
        return (int)p2;
    }
}  

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
{
    ArrayList<results> sortList = new ArrayList<results>();
    sortList.add(new results(prcTrait1));
    sortList.add(new results(prcTrait2));
    sortList.add(new results(prcTrait3));  

    Collections.sort(sortList);  

    results beginResults = sortList.get(0);
    results beginResults = sortList.get(1);
    results beginResults = sortList.get(2);  

    //It prints out the traits in their original order. Always.
}
```

That's one solution I saw.
Then this is another thing I'm trying:

**With Comparater**

```
public class personalityQuiz
{
    public double newPercent;
    //. . .
    public static class results
    {
        personalityQuiz v = new personalityQuiz();
        //v for variable 
        //That and I wanted it to be short because I would be using it alot. 
        public results(double percent)
        {
            v.newPercent = percent;
            percent*=100;
            System.out.printf("You are %.2f", percent);
            System.out.println();
        }
    }  
    public double getPercent
    {
        double xPercent = newPercent;
        return xPercent;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        ArrayList<results> sortList = new ArrayList<results>();
        sortList.add(new results(prcTrait1));
        sortList.add(new results(prcTrait2));
        sortList.add(new results(prcTrait3));  

        Collections.sort(sortList, new Comparator<results>()
        {
            public int compare(results p1, results p2)
            {
            personalityQuiz v = new personalityQuiz();
            double newP1 = p1.v.getPercent();
            double newP2 = p2.v.getPercent();
            if(newP1 < newP2)
            {
                return 1;
            }
            else if(newP2 < newP1)
            {
                return -1;
            }
            else
            {
                return 0;
            }
        });  

    results beginResults = sortList.get(0);
    results beginResults = sortList.get(1);
    results beginResults = sortList.get(2);
    //still prints them in their original order
    }
}
```

I apologize for the probable various mistakes in execution there.
I'm somewhat self-learning Java right now and what I know was basically self-taught as well.

Anyway, any help would be amazing.
And I'll try to be around to respond to any comments or answers quickly ^^~

Comment: you should not compare double values with `<` `>`. Use `Double` class and it's [compare method](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/lang/double_compare.htm).

Comment: and check this article please: http://www.java2s.com/Questions_And_Answers/Java-Data-Type/double/compare.htm here is detailed information on double data type in java.

Comment: In the second example, why is `personalityQuiz v = new personalityQuiz();` in the comparator?  You create a new object but never use `v`, so this just wastes time every time the sort decides to compare two objects, which could be a lot if your array gets large.

Comment: What are `prcTrait1`, `prcTrait2`, and `prcTrait3`?  For all we know, the "original order" is the correct order, since you haven't told us what the values are.

Comment: As far as I can tell, the sort in the second example is working fine.  The three lines that start with `results beginResults` aren't all legal, so I can't tell what code you're actually using to print the results.

Comment: P.S. Regarding this: "I wanted it to be short because I would be using it alot": Please get out of this habit.  Use more descriptive variable names, and learn to use an IDE that will help save you from having to type in the whole name each time.  This kind of thinking leads to programmers writing code that their fellow team members can't understand.  At some point, if you're going to be doing this seriously, read Robert Martin's "Clean Code".

Comment: @RafaelOsipov- I have tried the Compare method and it didn't work either.

Comment: @ajb- I left it as prcTrait1, 2, and 3 to show that they were random doubles. I don't know what they are until the tester tests, really. 
And what I'm doing to 'print' the results is calling the arraylist objects by creating an object. This works, to my knowledge, because they arraylist elements are objects and I'm creating an object to call them. 
Please try not to go to hard on me here, I am self teaching and fairly new at all of this. 
And I'm aware that one should use 'descriptive variable names' and whatnot. I just hadn't planned on sharing this nor showing to anyone. ^^;

Comment: Please show us the code you're using to print the results.  I don't understand the description you gave me.  Like I said, I tested it with your `Comparator` and your `Collections.sort` and it worked fine (it sorted in descending order, which is what I think you wanted), so the problem must be somewhere else.  P.S. If you weren't planning on sharing the code, I understand.  The "keep names short to save typing" is a mistake I've seen a lot through my career by programmers writing _production_ code, which is why I felt I needed to say something.

Comment: @ajb- How are you printing the results? Because the odd way I have it up there is working for me. It's exactly as I have it in the code. That might be what's causing the problem.

Comment: And as far as keeping the names short goes, I know it's a bad practice  and even when I'm just coding like this I probably shouldn't do it-- Just to get in the habit of using better names. But I was being lazy I guess. I'll remember that though because I do plan on pursuing this.
I'll be going to college to study it shortly ^^~

Comment: The "odd way you have it up there" shouldn't compile.  You're declaring `beginResults` three times.  Plus, you aren't printing anything after sorting, so even if you changed the name of two of the variables it wouldn't help.  I replaced those three lines with `for (results r : sortList) System.out.println(r.v.getPercent());`.

Comment: Ah, ha, maybe that's the problem.  You print something when you construct a **new** `results`, which happens before you do any sorting.  You don't print anything after sorting.  Are you looking at that output and thinking it's supposed to be the result of the sort?

Comment: @ajb- Okay, so I get what you mean by it wouldn't compile because of declaring that same variable three times. That's one thing I didn't type right up there. I had the same name but with numbers after them, I apologize deeply (beginResults1, beginResults2...). So that's probably why it compiles.

Comment: And should I try replacing those lines with that.. or.. Because in response to your second question- that's exactly what I'm doing.  So should I try fixing the fact that I'm constructing **new results** before I replace the lines?  (And I apologize also for my noobishness ^^')

Comment: @ajb-- Never mind, I got it. And I love you ^^~ If you want to make it an answer or something. I don't know if it really matters to you if you get credit for it but that was the solution!

Answer (score 2):

In your first example, I think you missed a few things (and `results` should be `Results`, also `CompareTo` should be `compareTo`) -

```
public static class Results implements Comparable<Results>
{
  private double rPercent; //I've tried public and just leaving it double
  public Results(double percent)
  {
    this.rPercent = percent;
    percent*=100;
    System.out.printf("You are %.2f%n", percent);
  }
  public double getPercent()
  {
    return rPercent;
  }
  @Override
  public int compareTo(Results result)
  {
    return new Double(getPercent()).compareTo(result.getPercent());
  }
}
```

Comment: I will try this and report back!  
And I apologize about the capitalization ^^;

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't work. It's very possibly just something I'm doing wrong elsewhere in the code though.

Answer (score 1):

In your compare method, try Double.compare(double x, double y).

EDIT: Elliott Frisch expanded on that

I'm going to be honest and say some of your code was hard to follow, it would be beneficial for you to learn the 'standards' of the Java programming language, such as classes always starting with a capitol letter etc..

In your first example, the reason they were always coming out in the same order is probably because of a rounding *error*. When you're converting a double to a integer, it was most probably less than 1 (but greater than 0) in magnitude. Hence it was being rounded down (or up) to 0. Meaning that the collections API was not sorting them as there were being seen as 'equal'.
Your second example I was not able to follow, sorry.

*-Thomas*

Comment: I've tried the compare method ^^; 
One of the many things I've tried, unfortunately. 

And I completely understand the rounding error now. Thank you! 

And sorry about the unfollowable code ^^;